# Ruby - Splitting arrays into multiple lines

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm trying to create a 7 x 6 game board.

The rows will be named A through F

The columns will be numbered from 1 to 7

**Desired Output**

```
|| A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 | A6 | A7 ||
|| B1 | B2 | B3 | B4 | B5 | B6 | B7 ||
|| C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5 | C6 | C7 ||
|| D1 | D2 | D3 | D4 | D5 | D6 | D7 ||
|| E1 | E2 | E3 | E4 | E5 | E6 | E7 ||
|| F1 | F2 | F3 | F4 | F5 | F6 | F7 ||
```

The solution will probably use while loops

```
letter = "A"
number = 1
while letter < "G"
  puts "|| "
  while number < 8
    puts "#{letter}#{number} |"
    number += 1
  end
  letter = letter.next.ord.chr
  number = 1
end
```

When I run the code in IRB, I get the following output.

```
||
A1 |
A2 |
A3 |
A4 |
A5 |
A6 |
A7 |
||
B1 |
B2 |
B3 |
B4 |
B5 |
B6 |
B7 |
||
C1 |
C2 |
C3 |
C4 |
C5 |
C6 |
C7 |
||
D1 |
D2 |
D3 |
D4 |
D5 |
D6 |
D7 |
||
E1 |
E2 |
E3 |
E4 |
E5 |
E6 |
E7 |
||
F1 |
F2 |
F3 |
F4 |
F5 |
F6 |
F7 |
```

How can I fix this output, so that it displays seven letter-number combos per line?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `puts` adds a new line. You might want to look into `print`.

Comment: @ptd is correct, you don't want to use `puts` as it adds a newline character. Ruby has a `sprintf` that will allow you to format strings pretty well. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf

Comment: @brennan Even better, String has a `%` method that makes that even easier. `sprintf('%02d', x)` is equivalent to `'%02d' % x`. That avoids having to use the `sprintf` method explicitly, making it a little more modern than 1970s C code.

Comment: If any of the answers were helpful,consider selecting the one you valued most.

Answer (score 3):

That's a terribly messy way of going about this. Most of the time you should just iterate over small sets or ranges:

```
('A'..'F').each do |l|
  puts '|| %s ||' % [
    (1..7).collect do |i|
      '%s%d' % [ l, i ]
    end.join(' | ')
  ]
end
```

It's usually a better strategy to compose parts of your solution and pass them up the chain than it is to have the low-level parts doing a lot of heavy lifting. This method is fairly modular, there's well defined points for changing the separators, the formatting of the individual squares, and the overall framing structure.

Comment: This is a nicer way of doing it :) +1

Comment: That's a great solution. This is much easier than my method.

Answer (score 3):

```
(0..41).each do
  |i| y, x = i.divmod(7)
  print x == 0 ? "|| " : " | "
  print %w[A B C D E F][y]
  print x + 1
  print " ||\n" if x == 6
end
```

Comment: Having `|i|` on a new line is a rather odd coding convention.

Answer (score 2):

You need to stop newlines. Use `print` not `puts` where necessary.

e.g./

```
letter = "A"
number = 1
while letter < "G"
  print "||"
  while number < 8
    print " #{letter}#{number} |"
    number += 1
  end
  puts "|"
  letter = letter.next.ord.chr
  number = 1
end
```

Comment: puts must have added a new line. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

Another way, without an inner loop:

```
combis = %w(A B C D E F).product %w(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
combis.each_slice(7){|row| puts "|| #{ row.map(&:join).join(' | ') } ||"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
def print_it(last_ltr, last_nbr)
  ('A'.."#{last_ltr}").each { |l|
    puts ['||', *(" #{l}1 |".." #{l}#{last_nbr} |").to_a, '|'].join }
end

print_it('F', 7)
|| A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 | A6 | A7 ||
|| B1 | B2 | B3 | B4 | B5 | B6 | B7 ||
|| C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5 | C6 | C7 ||
|| D1 | D2 | D3 | D4 | D5 | D6 | D7 ||
|| E1 | E2 | E3 | E4 | E5 | E6 | E7 ||
|| F1 | F2 | F3 | F4 | F5 | F6 | F7 ||
```